# Browser Multiples Tabs - JSF 1.2 ad

Tags: jsf

I'm working on a  `JSF 1.2` + `RichFaces` system.  This system is a kind of blog. Users can create their blogs and manage them.  Blogs are accessible by a url type this:

```
www.meublog.com/NameOfBlog
```

I used a single `Managed Bean` with session scope to make all controls. When the user accesses the blog, I use a filter that through the URL, which identified the blog being accessed, put the `ID` of the blog in the session and gave foward to the blog index.
I used this session `ManagedBean` to control everything in the view of the blog.
The problem is that the browser shares the same session between multiple tabs. When a user accesses the blog like this `www.meublog.com/julio` on one tab and `www.meublog.com/fulano` in another tab, I can not identify the two blogs because I have only one session established.

I wonder to know if anyone knows the correct path to follow here ...

Comment: I know nothing about jsf, but if the session contains the blog id then surely you know which blog is which?  I think I must be missing something.  Can you be a little clearer?

Comment: @SachinKainth: the HTTP session accounts for a single browser instance and is thus been shared among multiple browser tabs within the same browser instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store request scoped information in the session scope for exactly the reasons you're facing. Use a request scoped managed bean instead which get initialized based on the request URI. You can get most of the request details by [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) and/or [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

E.g., inside bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` method:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

// If you use suffix mapping like *.jsf
String servletPath = ec.getRequestServletPath(); 

// Or if you use prefix mapping like /faces/*
String pathInfo = ec.getRequestPathInfo();

// Now initialize based on the value of either servletPath or pathInfo.
```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)